# Return can close Loop for? (python/django)

Tags: python, django

Does `return` on python close the Loop for?
I'm asking that because I wrote a code that will search for me someone in a list and if know that person it will return me his age if not it will tell me "Person not found".
If the person is in the first place of the Array if find it but if it is in the second he doesn't why?

```
def lerDoBanco(name):
lista_names = [
    {'name': 'Joaquim', 'age': 20},
    {'name': 'João', 'age': 25},
    {'name': 'Ana', 'age': 27}
]

for person in lista_names:
    if person['name'] == name:
        return person
    else:
        return {'name': 'Person not found', 'age': 0}

def fname(request, name):
    result = lerDoBanco(name)
    if result['age'] > 0:
        return HttpResponse('The person was found, has ' + str(result['age']) + ' years old')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Person not found')
```

I ask that because if I comment the else statement it shows me all the people in the Array correctly.

Comment: From the moment you `return` you move out of the function, so out of the `for` loop as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` terminates execution further and returns some desired value (default is `None`). Change indentation to make your code working :

```
def lerDoBanco(name):
    lista_names = [
        {'name': 'Joaquim', 'age': 20},
        {'name': 'João', 'age': 25},
        {'name': 'Ana', 'age': 27}
    ]

    for person in lista_names:
        if person['name'] == name:
            return person
    return {'name': 'Person not found', 'age': 0}
```

It will iterate all the values to find the person then if not found then the default value `{'name': 'Person not found', 'age': 0}` will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `return` operator it will terminate the current function execution and return value. So if you will use `return` inside your loop, `return` will terminate the loop and the function and return some value.

Answer (score 0):

From the moment you `return` you move out of the function, so out of the `for` loop as well.

What you thus can do is simply `return` the `'Person not found'` at the end of the function:

```
def lerDoBanco(name):
    lista_names = [
        {'name': 'Joaquim', 'age': 20},
        {'name': 'João', 'age': 25},
        {'name': 'Ana', 'age': 27}
    ]

    for person in lista_names:
        if person['name'] == name:
            return person
    return {'name': 'Person not found', 'age': 0}
```

Note that if the data is stored in the database, it is better to make a queryset to filter at the *database side*. Databases are optimized to search effectively. You can also specify `db_index=True` on a column such that the database builds an index allowing much faster retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

A loop ends when one of the following happens:

1. loop condition evaluates to false
2. break is used
3. an exception is raised
4. a return statement is executed

The points above are the same for every programming language